# How to change the position of item availability left in stock in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, view.phtml

I want to change the position of items left in stock to after quantity i tried all solutions but still its not working out [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Login your either cpanel or ftp manager
2. Open the following path

> app/design/frontend/(your_package_name)/(your_theme_name)/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

3. Search for your content and change the position of that content to your desired position
4. If you didn't find at this location please enable [Template path hints](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html) and find the location at your root folder where your product's view.phtml file exists and search for your desired.